# Java: Add classpath the CustomClassLoader

Tags: java, class, import, classpath

I have the following CustomClassLoader

```
    /*
 * To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package Java;

/**
 *
 * @author noconnor
 */
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.security.AccessControlContext;
import java.security.AccessController;
import java.security.PrivilegedExceptionAction;
import org.apache.commons.io.FilenameUtils;

public class CustomClassLoader extends ClassLoader {

    private static String repoLocation = "C:/TempBINfolder/bin/";

    public CustomClassLoader() {
    }

    public CustomClassLoader(ClassLoader parent) {
        super(parent);
    }

    @Override
    protected Class<?> findClass(final String name)
            throws ClassNotFoundException {

        AccessControlContext acc = AccessController.getContext();

        try {
            return (Class) AccessController.doPrivileged(
                    new PrivilegedExceptionAction() {

                        public Object run() throws ClassNotFoundException {

                            FileInputStream fi = null;
                            try {

                                String fileName = FilenameUtils.getBaseName(name);
                                String path = FilenameUtils.getFullPath(name);
                                setRepoLocation(path);
                                fi = new FileInputStream(getRepoLocation() + fileName + ".class");

                                ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                                byte[] buffer = new byte[8192];
                                int read;
                                while ((read = fi.read(buffer)) > 0) {
                                    baos.write(buffer, 0, read);
                                }
                                byte[] classBytes = baos.toByteArray();

                                return defineClass(fileName, classBytes, 0,
                                        classBytes.length);
                            } catch (Exception e) {
                                throw new ClassNotFoundException(name);
                            }
                        }
                    }, acc);
        } catch (java.security.PrivilegedActionException pae) {
            return super.findClass(name);
        }
    }

    public String getRepoLocation() {
        return repoLocation;
    }

    public void setRepoLocation(String repoLocation) {
        this.repoLocation = repoLocation;
    }
}
```

And it works find out for most classes, I ran into a problem do. I have the following java class

```
    public class IntegerComparator 
             implements Comparator<Integer>
{
   public IntegerComparator(){}

   public int compare(Integer a, Integer b)
   {  int aValue = a.intValue();
      int bValue = b.intValue();
      return (aValue - bValue);
   }  
}
```

This class implements a custom Comparator which is located in the same project as this class but this is not picked up by the class loader and bombs out from loading the class. It does not give any errors but if i add the following line to the class

```
import java.util.Comparator;
```

The CustomClassLoader works. This leads me to believe that I am missing a classpath for the file or something like that. Does anybody know how to solve this?

**EDIT:** This is the code that is calling the class loader

```
Class stringClass = null;

        for (String file : classFiles) {
            ClassLoader cls = new CustomClassLoader(ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader());
            try {
                stringClass = cls.loadClass(file);
                tempList.add(stringClass);
            } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(CompilerForm.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
        }
```

I want it to loop through to load more than one file if there is more than one file

**EDIT:** -verbose output

```
[Loaded java.net.MalformedURLException from C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_05\jre\lib\rt.jar]
[Loaded Java.CustomClassLoader$1 from file:/C:/projects/Compiler/Compiler/build/classes/]
[Loaded java.lang.ClassFormatError from C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_05\jre\lib\rt.jar]
[Loaded org.junit.runners.model.MultipleFailureException from file:/C:/projects/Compiler/Compiler/Jar%20Files/junit-4.11-SNAPSHOT-20120416-1530.jar]
[Loaded org.junit.runner.notification.Failure from file:/C:/projects/Compiler/Compiler/Jar%20Files/junit-4.11-SNAPSHOT-20120416-1530.jar]
[Loaded java.io.StringWriter from C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_05\jre\lib\rt.jar]
[Loaded org.junit.runner.notification.RunNotifier$4 from file:/C:/projects/Compiler/Compiler/Jar%20Files/junit-4.11-SNAPSHOT-20120416-1530.jar]
[Loaded org.junit.runner.notification.RunNotifier$7 from file:/C:/projects/Compiler/Compiler/Jar%20Files/junit-4.11-SNAPSHOT-20120416-1530.jar]
[Loaded org.junit.runner.notification.RunNotifier$2 from file:/C:/projects/Compiler/Compiler/Jar%20Files/junit-4.11-SNAPSHOT-20120416-1530.jar]
```

Comment: "Bombs out" means what, exactly? And while it's nice to see the classloader code, where's the code that uses it?

Comment: when I try to load the class (while debugging) it just moves straight out of the method, which is strange as it does not give an error message, but as mentioned above, if i add the import statement, it will load the class successfully

Comment: added the code calling the CustomClassLoader

Answer (score 1):

What if you add `-verbose` as a parameter to JVM when running. You'll see classloading details.

Comment: do you know how to do this in Netbeans, I know how to do this in eclipse but I do not know how to do this in Netbeans?

Comment: Give a try to following: click on the project -> Properties -> select Run -> VM Options is your line

Comment: +1 for the -verbose: but i have never used -verbose before, i have added the output straight after it moves out of the customclassloader, any idea what is going on from this output?

Comment: It actually displays what class is loaded from what location. Details and other parameters can be found here e.g. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/windows/java.html